# openssl_encrypt & AES256

Tags: php, aes, php-openssl

maybe someone know how do this on PHP

> echo "TEST" | openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -k 123456 -a -md md5

i will try like

> ```
> $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
> $data = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt('TEST', 'aes-256-cbc', $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
> ```

but not success..

Comment: Just based on the name of that variable `$password`... I would certainly hope you aren't encrypting user login passwords instead of hashing them like you should be.

Comment: Yea you need to hash passwords, not encrypt them.

Comment: guys: bad choice of variable name by the OP (although I do hope he's not trying to encrypt passwords). The third parameter to openssl_encrypt is the encryption key.

Comment: you are kidding ?)))
i am so stupid and cant set variable $password ?)
--
result diferent, ecnrypt from console and like php...

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, like the version at https://linux.die.net/man/1/enc , the man page for my local openssl installation lists '-md' (without an argument) as an option for openssl enc - but doesn't seem to explain what its for. The [openssl wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Enc) says its used for key derivation.

A bit more digging and I found [this on the SO cryptography site](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption/35614#35614).

But before attempting to write an implementation, since openssl's implementation is somewhat esoteric, it rather begs the question of whether there is a need to specifically support this in your implementation? If you merely need a method of encrypting/decrypting data outside your website, you could just write a command line PHP script.

A quick read through the linked document, suggests that....

```
  $data = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt('TEST', 'aes-256-cbc', md5($password, true), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
```

But I expect that openssl is doing something else to the key in the derivation function to pad the 16 bytes out to the required 128 bits (why are you forcing a 128 bit key for a 256 bit algorithm?)

Comment: Thx for normal answer ;)
about forcing algoritm i dont know, iam find example on php.net and trying to do like example...

i try code as you paste but this example also not works ;(((
and result diferent...

Comment: about -md i also try to find normal answer, and cant find.. what that argument do..

Comment: openssl with work variant return like that ecnrypted string
`U2FsdGVkX1+EHk4P8i2vv68U0k6ff0nn3MNxCWQnKOga3FQJKZjV2Nv3CKm36eUH`

your varian return like that
`SSUsMVwk7XEJPVEmnHHTBA==`

Comment: Of course it does. If you don't understand the difference in length, and the obvious solutions for key stretching maybe you're out of your depth a bit here?

Comment: maybe... i will try more variats today, but still nothing...
i think better use openssl_digest
but i still not understand how...
if encrypt all message, text seems fine, but not works... if crypt only keys, sting again small.