# CryptoJS decrypting from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, aes, cryptojs

Here's my PHP code:

```
$cipher = 'aes-256-cbc';
// 128-bit key
$key = md5('super secret', true);
// 128-bit IV
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($message, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

error_log(__FILE__ . __LINE__ . ' key: ' . bin2hex($key));
error_log(__FILE__ . __LINE__ . ' iv: ' . bin2hex($iv));
error_log(__FILE__ . __LINE__ . ' ciphertext: ' . bin2hex($ciphertext));

file_put_contents($courseOutlineFile, bin2hex($iv) . bin2hex($ciphertext));
```

And my Javascript code, where res is the text from the ajax response to read the file generated by PHP:

```
var k = CryptoJS.MD5('super secret');
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(res.substring(0, 32));
var data = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(res.substring(32));

console.log("key: ", CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(k))
console.log("iv: ", CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(iv))
console.log("ciphertext: ", CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(data))

var cipher = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
    ciphertext: data
});

var dec = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipher, k, {
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
});
console.log("decrypted:", dec.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex));

var json = dec.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log("json:", json)
```

I've verified with a compare tool that the hex values of the key, IV, and data are the same in PHP and what gets printed to the browser's console.  It does successfully decrypt (something), but that last console.log statement generates an error: Error: "Malformed UTF-8 data".  If I try Latin1 it results in a bunch of non-printable characters.

The $message variable that I'm encrypting is the output from json_encode on an array.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

These are the first 80 hex digits of the decrypted result, the entire thing is a little under 28k hex digits.

> 20a290156abf2855f2c3344a2d9cf7dc84c5c02b1a48a03f18aa8a5054f650dd5517b25b6582c72d

Here's a complete example:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$jsonObj = [
  'el1' => 'val1',
  'ar1' => [
    'el2' => 'val2',
    'el3' => 'val3',
  ],
];
$message = json_encode($jsonObj);
echo $message . '<br>';
$cipher = 'aes-256-cbc';
// 128-bit key
$key = md5('super secret', true);
// 128-bit IV
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($message, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

echo ' key: ' . bin2hex($key) . '<br>';
echo ' iv: ' . bin2hex($iv) . '<br>';
echo ' ciphertext: ' . bin2hex($ciphertext) . '<br>';

echo bin2hex($iv) . bin2hex($ciphertext);
```

The output:

```
{"el1":"val1","ar1":{"el2":"val2","el3":"val3"}}
key: 5f1903f5f2cb32acb4c1dcae9e30d374
iv: bfdb765d1ca4734c5748ffb9883dd15c
ciphertext: 
02717027440040375f7e0dbea69e77783949d3c160529eef0b9d59a751a2a312fa137a5034f6f4c9f89a348ef3f96fce40c8afe0c8a20a2f7a2535417cca2dd2
bfdb765d1ca4734c5748ffb9883dd15c02717027440040375f7e0dbea69e77783949d3c160529eef0b9d59a751a2a312fa137a5034f6f4c9f89a348ef3f96fce40c8afe0c8a20a2f7a2535417cca2dd2
```

And the Javascript:

```
res = 'bfdb765d1ca4734c5748ffb9883dd15c02717027440040375f7e0dbea69e77783949d3c160529eef0b9d59a751a2a312fa137a5034f6f4c9f89a348ef3f96fce40c8afe0c8a20a2f7a2535417cca2dd2';
var k = CryptoJS.MD5('super secret');
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(res.substring(0, 32));
var data = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(res.substring(32));

console.log("key: ", CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(k))
console.log("iv: ", CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(iv))
console.log("ciphertext: ", CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(data))

var cipher = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
    ciphertext: data
});

var dec = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipher, k, {
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
});
console.log("dec:", dec.toString());
console.log("decrypted:", dec.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex));
var json = dec.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log("json:", json)
// parse the JSON string to get the object
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

And the console output:

```
key:  5f1903f5f2cb32acb4c1dcae9e30d374 
iv:  bfdb765d1ca4734c5748ffb9883dd15c 
ciphertext:  02717027440040375f7e0dbea69e77783949d3c160529eef0b9d59a751a2a312fa137a5034f6f4c9f89a348ef3f96fce40c8afe0c8a20a2f7a2535417cca2dd2 
dec: 50d411522f2d08b34d68f847fb78e0cfabf1144f933d83839431732a473079d9b3ed843e120d9ad6a239 
decrypted: 50d411522f2d08b34d68f847fb78e0cfabf1144f933d83839431732a473079d9b3ed843e120d9ad6a239 

Error during decryption:  Error: "Malformed UTF-8 data"
```

Comment: Those 80 bytes are not plain text when converted to ASCII. I'd suggest your decryption is not happening properly.

Comment: Try creating a [mcve] with something that will not be 28 kb long.

Comment: @miken32 I've edited my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225904/openssl-encrypt-aes256/49226163#49226163

Comment: Sweet buttery crumpets, I'm using a 128-bit key for a 256-bit algorithm.  I even pointed that out in a comment.  If only I had completed the thought, haha.  Thanks.